# elementary OS bootable USB not booting up

Tags: boot, usb, thinkpad

I created a Bootable usb for elementary os using etcher however when I try to boot from it on my Lenovo thinkpad x1 carbon (gen 7) it gets stuck at a black screen after selecting try elementary OS without installing from the grub. I tried the same usb stick on another laptop and it was able to bootup properly. I have turned off secure boot on my lenovo x1 carbon. Also, I have previously installed Ubuntu and manjaro on the same machine successfully. I don't know why elementary OS is running into issues.

Update: Tried with 'nomodeset', tried different software like Rufus, UnetBootin and Etcher to create bootable.

Comment: If you get to the GRUB selection screen it is nothing wrong with the "boot-able" part of the USB, it's already past that stage when GRUB kicks in. Have you upgraded the BIOS lately? This sounds like some BIOS bug to me.

Comment: I had the same error on Hera. I guess that there is an issue with the installer... It works like a charm in the new installer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to boot using a parameter **nomodeset**. Select 'Try elementary os without installing' and press 'e' on you keyboard. Then edit the line containing `quiet splash` so it became `quiet splash nomodeset ---` and then Ctrl+x to boot with this parameter.

There is a similar question here, so this one is a duplicate. You should avoid that.

Comment: Tried nomodeset it doesn't work, failed with same result. I remember using nomodeset for Laptops with Nvidia GPUs. However, Lenovo thinkpad x1 c doesn't have one.

Comment: I see a lot of people complain about that newer laptops cannot boot with elementary live usb.. I do not know if yours is a new one but nomodeset is not only for Nvidia graphic cards - the nomodeset parameter instructs the kernel to not load video drivers and use BIOS modes(low resolution) instead until X is loaded. >>  https://askubuntu.com/a/716966/730454